# Running bat file with pushd

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am running this inside of Jenkins in execute with batch script

```
pushd \\NXXXX.xxxx.se\XX\XXXXXInstaller\
echo "Startar installation..."
dir
Installera_XXXXX.bat
popd
```

The problem is that it wont start the bat script. Why?

Everything seems fine. Even the dir works fine but then I get:
The system cannot find the path specified.

```
12:28:24 E:\WS\Jenkins\workspace\Test136>pushd     \\NXXXXXX.XXXXX.se\XXXXX\XXXXXInstaller 
12:28:24 
12:28:24 Z:\XXXXXInstaller>echo "Startar installation..." 
12:28:24 "Startar installation..."
12:28:24 
12:28:24 Z:\XXXXXInstaller>dir
12:28:24  Volume in drive Z is Drive-E
12:28:24  Volume Serial Number is 2466-A05A
12:28:24 
12:28:24  Directory of Z:\XXXXXInstaller
12:28:24 
12:28:24 2015-11-25  10:12    <DIR>          .
12:28:24 2015-11-25  10:12    <DIR>          ..
12:28:24 2010-11-18  20:27           587ÿ776 7za.exe
12:28:24 2015-09-24  09:14               402 Installera_XXXXX.bat
12:28:24                2 File(s)        588ÿ178 bytes
12:28:24                2 Dir(s)   2ÿ561ÿ781ÿ760 bytes free
12:28:24 
12:28:24 Z:\XXXXXInstaller>Installera_XXXXX.bat
12:28:24 The system cannot find the path specified.
12:28:24 File Not Found
```

Comment: Can you add the script output to your question? It will help to solve your problem.

Comment: So, _XXXXX\XXXXXInstaller_ is a share on _NXXXXXX.XXXXX.se_ . Does the behavior change if you invoke the script manually? Also if connecting to _NXXXXXX.XXXXX.se_ and going to _Z:\XXXXXInstaller_ and launching _Installera_XXXXX.bat_ manually does it give you the same error? Do you have execute permissions on the (remote) folder?

Comment: What is IN Installera_XXXXX.bat ?

Comment: Also the commands: `pushd \\NXXXX.xxxx.se\XX\XXXXXInstaller` and `E:\WS\Jenkins\workspace\Test136>pushd     \\NXXXXXX.XXXXX.se\XXXXX\XXXXXInstaller` are a little bit different in terms of number of __X__ es (I assume that _X_ is a placeholder for something variable)

Comment: All the X is something I put in so you cant read it.

Comment: I think that the "The system cannot find the path specified." error is generated by some commands in your Installera_XXXXX.bat file. Can you try to simplify your batch file (for example, just use a echo command) and try to re-launch your job?

Comment: Where are you running your batch file, and where is the `Installera_XXXXX.bat` file? to call this, use `call Installera_XXXXX.bat`; otherwise execution won't return to this batch script here...

Comment: Bruno. You are correct. It does read it and run it but it is inside the script the error is. :-) Thx